# Battery stuck at Waiting to Charge

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

Recently bought a new ASUS laptop and have been enjoying Ubuntu 19.10 with it. Recently, however, I've come accross a weird issue I'm not sure how to tackle.
Today, after booting the laptop, the battery indicator showed it was not charging despite being at 97% and it being plugged. Despite this, some charging must be taking place, since that 97% hasn't dropped a single point since booting up the computer.

Power Statistics shows the battery as Waiting to Charge, and when unplugging and plugging the charger I can hear the Ubuntu sound prompt.

Does anyone know what may be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have this problem with my Asus laptop now and then.  Power reset will usually fix it. See `Fix 3 ` in  https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/asus-laptop-plugged-in-not-charging-solved/ The page is for Windows users but it's a hardware power issue so the fix applies.

Answer (score 1):

Constantly charging a battery reduces its total capacity, its ability to deliver power when disconnected. Therefore, charging logic is designed to restart charging only when the battery runs down to a specific voltage level, and this is normal.